# tb dropdown doesn't work on smartphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've now tried several things and googled a lot, but so far to no avail.

I've been working on a project with twitter bootstrap and made ​​a dropdown in the navigation. Everything works on the desktop but einwadnfrei on the smartphone I have extreme problems and can click a link in the dropdown. The menu includes with every click.

This one i have write in the index

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="index"><a href="index.html" title="TPNO">tpno</a></li>
    <li class="diensten dropdown">
    <a href="#" title="Diensten" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">DIENSTEN <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="interim.html" title="Interim">Interim Management</a></li>
            <li><a href="case.html" title="Case management">Case Management</a></li>
            <li><a href="conflict.html" title="Conflictbemiddeling">Conflictbemiddeling</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="profile"><a href="profiel.html" title="Profiel">Profiel</a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

And this is what i include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

But it doesnt work on smartphone. I have forgotten something or done wrong? would be grateful for your help.

Comment: What doctype are you using? Could you post a link to the page, or create a jsfiddle with the full source. Could be something else on the page messing things up. The only thing I see wrong in your code is a missing semicolon after `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()`.

Comment: Also, try moving the script tags for bootstrap.js and bootstrap-dropdown.js to the top, directly under jquery.js

Comment: Hey kaisoz,thanks for help. I have added the semicolon. Here is the link: http://tpno.nl

Comment: So thanks again for the answers. Myself have found the problem. It lies on the bootstrap dropdown.js have replaced this and now it works. I can now press the left side of the smartphone.